# Closing connection to user before PHP scripts ends

Tags: php

I am trying to push a 1x1 pixel image out to my user and do some other operations on the server after the fact.  However, the connection will not close out until everything is done in this script.

```
 ignore_user_abort(true);     

 // turn off gzip compression
 if ( function_exists( 'apache_setenv' ) ) {
   apache_setenv( 'no-gzip', 1 );
 }     

 ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);     

 // turn on output buffering if necessary
 if (ob_get_level() == 0) {
   ob_start();
 }     

 // removing any content encoding like gzip etc.
 header('Content-encoding: none', true);     

 //check to ses if request is a POST
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   // the GIF should not be POSTed to, so do nothing...
   echo ' ';
 } else {
   // return 1x1 pixel transparent gif
   header("Content-type: image/gif");
   // needed to avoid cache time on browser side
   header("Content-Length: 42");
   header("Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate");
   header("Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 2000 12:59:00 GMT");
   header("Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jan 2006 12:59:00 GMT");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");     

   echo sprintf('%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%',71,73,70,56,57,97,1,0,1,0,128,255,0,192,192,192,0,0,0,33,249,4,1,0,0,0,0,44,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,2,68,1,0,59);    
 }     

 // flush all output buffers.
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 ob_end_flush();

 // How can I close the connection to client and do some long operations here. exit() wont work.
 // client continues to load image, spinning status.
 super_long_function("30 second script");
 // client gets success
```

Comment: There is no direct way unless you want to [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) another PHP script and have it run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentions, you need to run another script, but just calling exec won't do it. You need to do something like this:

```
exec( 'bash -c "exec nohup setsid *ENTER COMMAND* > /dev/null 2>&1 &"' );
```

This will run a script in the background and allow your script to close. Just using exec will run a script in PHP and wait for it to finish. You want something like:

```
exec( 'bash -c "exec nohup setsid php LongExecScript.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &"' );
```

Alternatively, can you save their data and use cron? The best option IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this may does the trick (disclaimer you may need to tweak some parts) .

```
<?php
 ob_start();

 header('Connection: close');
 header("Content-Length: 0");

 ob_end_flush();
 ob_flush();
 flush();

 // to flush the session to disk if not needed anymore
 if (session_id())
     session_write_close(); 
?>
```

**Keep in mind if HTTP clients ignore the HTTP 1.1 Connection: close header this wont work**